# Cython with numpy how to get rid of fancy indexing (no call to Python)

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I want to release the GIL inside a for loop on a 3-dimensional numpy array

```
cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t,ndim=3] array=np.ones((10000000,4,2))
cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t,ndim=2] sliced_array
cdef int i
cdef int N=array.shape[0]
for i in range(N):
  sliced_array=array[i]
  #perform computations on slice
```

When I look at the html produced by Cython it looks like it is calling Python when it is doing `sliced_array=array[i]` I guess it is because it infers the size of the two other dimensions but even when using typed ranges for the second and third axis this line is still yellow !

```
sliced_array=array[i,typed_slice_x,typed_slice_y]
```

Comment: I didn't work with Cython, but `slice` is a Python builtin, this may cause the issue.

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: Try to rename the variable.

Comment: No it is not that

Comment: But good catch still

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the advantages of the newer memoryview syntax over declaring things as numpy arrays is that you can do indexing operations without the GIL:

```
cdef double[:,:,:] array=np.ones((10000000,4,2))
cdef double[:,:] sliced_array
cdef int i
cdef int N=array.shape[0]
for i in range(N):
  with nogil: # just to prove the point
    sliced_array=array[i,:,:]
```

If you declare them as `cdef np.ndarray` then you can't easily avoid needing the GIL for indexing.

Comment: Ok thanks again @DavidW I need to buy a book on Python it seems I really need to learn some more about how Python is working internally not to be stuck every damn time.